# How does PrincipalPermission(Attribute) work?

Tags: c#, .net, security, attributes

I am working on building a custom declarative security attribute, similar to the PrincipalPermissionAttribute.  After doing some research on the Attribute architecture within the .net Framework, attributes are instantiated only when Type.GetCustomAttributes is called. [See Here,](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/71s1zwct.aspx) [And Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305700/net-when-are-attributes-instantiated-and-can-i-get-a-reference-to-the-type-the)

So how is the PrincipalPermissionAttribute able to assert security actions at runtime if the method attributes were never instantiated?  I cannot find any documentation on how the PrincipalPermissionAttribute actually works.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The CLR actually looks for and triggers runtime execution of instances of attributes that inherit from [System.Security.Permissions.CodeAccessSecurityAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.codeaccesssecurityattribute.aspx).  If you want to build a declarative security attribute without resorting to AOP extensions, you pretty much have to inherit from this class.

Comment: Thanks for the info Nicole.  Since there does not appear to be any methods on the CodeAccessSecurityAttribute which perform the security check, I see no way to override the logic.  AOP may be the only option.

Comment: The security check is done by the IPermission implementation created by the attribute's CreatePermission method override.  For a simple example, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eugene_bobukh/archive/2004/03/10/87645.aspx.  If you're interested in anything more complicated, your best bet is probably to grab a decompiler like Reflector to look at the innards of the built-in permission types since creation of custom permissions and attributes is not heavily documented.

Comment: @NicoleCalinoiu Can you define AOP extensions please?

Comment: @CRice: AOP = "aspect oriented programming".  For example, one could use a tool like [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/) to [translate any attribute into a security check at method entry injected into your assembly's IL](https://www.postsharp.net/aop.net).  One could also do this sort of thing at runtime by using inversion of control coupled with a proxy approach for runtime AOP (e.g.: using a DI container with [Castle DynamicProxy](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/)).